# Filtering a collection the map is not showing the filtered results

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-filter

I filter an image collection by a country which seems to works well but when I show the results on the map they appeared not filtered:

```java
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var vn_shape = ee.Feature(
  countries
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Argentina'))
    .first()
    );
print (vn_shape);
Map.addLayer(vn_shape, {color: 'black'}, 'Country');

var firesAus = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
             .filterBounds(vn_shape.geometry())
             .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-01-31');
print('Size Country Fires', firesAus.size())

Map.addLayer(firesAus, {color: '00FFFF'}, 'Fires');
Map.setCenter(-64.03, -31.54, 3)
```

I wanted the fires appeared only inside the country, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIRMS images are global, so no matter which bounds you filter to, you'll get all images. If you want to show where you had fires during your date range, you can do this:

```
var firesAus = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
             .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-01-31')

var fireImage = firesAus
  .max()
  .clip(vn_shape.geometry())

Map.addLayer(fireImage, {color: '00FFFF'}, 'Fires')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5699262c00efe6c9bd9d96ebac3592a5

Comment: I don't quite understand the difference, I mean why filterBounds do not filter only the data for the region?

Comment: filterBounds() only keeps images that intersects the bounds. The images in the FIRMS image collection cover the whole world. So, no matter which bounds you specify, you'll never filter anything out. https://code.earthengine.google.com/8fdea20f30039803503740063b2bad9f